# Porque o a resposta fica diferente naocodigo fora da função ? A primeira sai a lista dos carros, ja na função sai somente o primeiro?

Tags: python-3.x

```
data = [{'marca': 'fiat','modelo': 'uno','preco': 10000,'combustivel': 'gasolina'},
        {'marca': 'fiat','modelo': 'palio','preco': 12000,'combustivel': 'alcool'},
        {'marca': 'fiat','modelo': 'punto','preco': 15000,'combustivel': 'flex'},
        {'marca': 'gm','modelo': 'vectra','preco': 25000,'combustivel': 'gasolina'},
        {'marca': 'gm','modelo': 'celta','preco': 11000,'combustivel': 'alcool'},
        {'marca': 'gm','modelo': 'corsa','preco': 17000,'combustivel': 'flex'}]

for carros in data:
    if carros["combustivel"] == 'gasolina':
        mod_gasolina = carros["modelo"]
        print(mod_gasolina)

def veiculos_gasolina2(gasolina2):
    for carros in gasolina2:
        if carros["combustivel"] == 'gasolina':
            mod_gasolina = carros["modelo"]
            return mod_gasolina

carros = veiculos_gasolina2(list(data))
print(carros)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está retornando o primeiro item da lista em que a condição `mod_gasolina = carros["modelo"]` é verdadeira.

O que você deveria estar fazendo, é criar uma nova lista, adicionar todos os carros que atenderem a condição nessa lista, e então retornar a lista.

Exemplo:

```
carros = [{'marca': 'fiat','modelo': 'uno','preco': 10000,'combustivel': 'gasolina'},
        {'marca': 'fiat','modelo': 'palio','preco': 12000,'combustivel': 'alcool'},
        {'marca': 'fiat','modelo': 'punto','preco': 15000,'combustivel': 'flex'},
        {'marca': 'gm','modelo': 'vectra','preco': 25000,'combustivel': 'gasolina'},
        {'marca': 'gm','modelo': 'celta','preco': 11000,'combustivel': 'alcool'},
        {'marca': 'gm','modelo': 'corsa','preco': 17000,'combustivel': 'flex'}]


def filtrar_por_gasolina(carros):
    modelos_a_gasolina = []
    for carro in carros:
        if carro['combustivel'] == 'gasolina':
            modelos_a_gasolina.append(carro['modelo'])
    return modelos_a_gasolina

modelos_a_gasolina = filtrar_por_gasolina(carros)
print(modelos_a_gasolina)
```

Ou alternativamente, escreva a função utilizando compreensão de listas:

```
def filtrar_por_gasolina(carros):
    return [carro['modelo'] for carro in carros if carro['combustivel'] == 'gasolina']
```

Comment: Muito obrigado....